# Проблема в выводе ошибки 404 страница не найдена

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error404

Я хочу в своем проекте вывести ошибку 404 страница не найдена, в том случае если неправильный адрес будет. Я написал код но он не работает.

ErrorController

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

        ModelAndView errorPage = new ModelAndView("errorPage");
        String errorMsg = "";
        int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(httpRequest);

        switch (httpErrorCode) {
            case 400: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 400. Bad Request";
                break;
            }
            case 401: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 401. Unauthorized";
                break;
            }
            case 404: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found";
                break;
            }
            case 500: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 500. Internal Server Error";
                break;
            }
        }
        errorPage.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);
        return errorPage;
    }

    private int getErrorCode(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (Integer) httpRequest
          .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "500Error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void throwRuntimeException() {
    throw new NullPointerException("Throwing a null pointer exception");
}
}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Ошибка или просто пустая страница? В дебаггере смотреле, что приходит в httpErrorCode?

Comment: Просто томкатоская ошибка, не выводит типа страница не найдена и тд

Comment: Посмотрите в моем проекте все ли файлы есть, может чего то не хватает(

Comment: В режиме дебаггера, что у вас находится в переменной `httpErrorCode` на строчке `switch (httpErrorCode) {` ?

Comment: Я включил отладчик но там ничего не показывает

Comment: Судя-повсему вы не поставили точку остановы. Посмотрите [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-p_Rs4rmX64), если у вас Eclipse или  [это](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/753-rukovodstvo-poljhzovatelja-intellij-idea-otladchik), если у вас intellij-idea. А если вы делали всё правильно, то смотрите по коду "выше" почему у вас ничего не приходит туда, куда вам нужно

Comment: У меня нетбинс)

Comment: Может  я что не дописал в туториале есть web.xml но в моем проект web,xml заменяет WebMvcConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы перехватить любую ошибку нужно ввести ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public String notFound() {
        return "error/404";
    }

}
```

Так же нужно унаследовать ваш контроллер от AbstractErrorController:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController extends AbstractErrorController {

    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @Autowired
    public ErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleErrors(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);

        if (status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
            throw new NotFoundException();

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(getErrorAttributes(request, false));
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }

}
```

Соответсвенно по пути view/error/404.jsp:

```
<h1>404</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо) не подскажите надо новый класс создавать?

Comment: Вам просто нужно изменить ваш существующий ErrorController, унаследовавшись от AbstractErrorController. Можно скопировать и вставить представленный класс. И создать еще один ControllerAdvice, так называемый глобальный перехвадчик. Для отслеживания NotFoundException.

Comment: ControllerAdvice  в том же пакете создать?

Comment: Посмотрите я добавил картинку у меня ошибка

Comment: Да в том же пакете контроллеров. Какая там ошибка написана?

Comment: cannot find symbol - ErrorAtribtutes

Comment: Это ваша среда разработки так реагирует, оно содержиться в spring-boot-mvc зависимости. Попробуйте открыть ваш проект допустим в intellij idea.

Comment: Мне нужно только на нетбинсе его сделать, другого выхода нет

Comment: можете помочь реализовать его на нетбинсе пожалуйста

Comment: мне срочно надо

Comment: Я думаю это проблема NetBeans, на intellijidea у меня все получается. Это другая проблема я предполагаю.

Comment: можете помочь как можно в моем проекте реализовать это

Comment: Создавайте новый вопрос

Comment: сейчас  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972581/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-404-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0